# Html & Css image border with a gif

Tags: html, css, border

I'm trying to build an ASP.Net web application, and as a part of it i'm using a gif that I want to apply a border too. Here's my code:

```
<img src="GemsIconGif.gif" width="42" height="42" alt="Gems" style="border-color:Gray; border-bottom:1px; border-left:1px; border-right:1px; border-top:4px; border-width:5px; border-radius: 6px;"/>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try this: `<img src="GemsIconGif.gif" width="42" height="42" alt="Gems" style="border-color: red; border-width:5px; border-radius: 6px;"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give `border-style` give border style to image.

like:

```
border-style: solid;
```

Or any you want. Hope it solved your issue.

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aqoaLjc1/1/)

Comment: @A.Abramov You should mark as answer if it solved your issue.